# Highcharts Stacking Bar misaligned and oddly sized bars

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts, bar-chart

I have created a fiddle for this chart and the issues I'm having: https://jsfiddle.net/emergingdzns/9g95pobg/4/

**Background:** I am trying to create a stacked bar chart for two particular set of words, 15 that are positive sentiment and 15 that are negative sentiment. In the fiddle example above, I am creating the data set where the x axis (vertical) starts at 1 and goes through 19. Each word has a positive or negative score of 1-5 (or -1 to -5). So in order to get them to show up side-by-side I loop through them in PHP and set the same value for "x" on each of a set of words where the sentiment value is inversely equal. So a word with positive sentiment of 4 is matched to a word of negative sentiment of -4. Sometimes there is an uneven number of words with the same inverse value so they are added to an "x" position without a corresponding word. (You can see that in the fiddle output). The "y" axis is the number of times the word was used in this particular query.

**Issue 1:** I can't seem to get the bars at each "x" position to align. Ultimately we want the graph to look something like the Highchart demo for bar with negative stack (http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-negative-stack). However, in their example, the dataset for their series is just a bunch of numbers. We needed full data so we had to use an object so we could have the word and it's sentiment value along with it's y value (number of times used).

**Issue 2:** The bars are different thicknesses/heights on our page (which doesn't seem to be an issue in the fiddle). You can see this in the screenshot here:
[image]

Here is the code from the fiddle:

```
<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
<script>
$(function () {
    var allPositiveData = [{"sentimentName":"xoxoxo","y":2,"sentimentValue":4,"x":1},{"sentimentName":"amazing","y":3,"sentimentValue":4,"x":2},{"sentimentName":"awesome","y":6,"sentimentValue":4,"x":3},{"sentimentName":"terrific","y":1,"sentimentValue":4,"x":4},{"sentimentName":"wow","y":5,"sentimentValue":4,"x":5},{"sentimentName":"exciting","y":1,"sentimentValue":3,"x":6},{"sentimentName":"happy","y":2,"sentimentValue":3,"x":7},{"sentimentName":"excited","y":2,"sentimentValue":3,"x":8},{"sentimentName":"excellent","y":1,"sentimentValue":3,"x":9},{"sentimentName":"great","y":15,"sentimentValue":3,"x":10},{"sentimentName":"heartfelt","y":1,"sentimentValue":3,"x":11},{"sentimentName":"love","y":7,"sentimentValue":3,"x":12},{"sentimentName":"loved","y":1,"sentimentValue":3,"x":13},{"sentimentName":"grateful","y":4,"sentimentValue":3,"x":14},{"sentimentName":"lovely","y":2,"sentimentValue":3,"x":15}];
    var allNegativeData = [{"sentimentName":"damn","y":-1,"sentimentValue":-4,"x":1},{"sentimentName":"dead","y":-3,"sentimentValue":-3,"x":6},{"sentimentName":"angry","y":-1,"sentimentValue":-3,"x":7},{"sentimentName":"horrible","y":-1,"sentimentValue":-3,"x":8},{"sentimentName":"loss","y":-6,"sentimentValue":-3,"x":9},{"sentimentName":"losing","y":-1,"sentimentValue":-3,"x":10},{"sentimentName":"bad","y":-2,"sentimentValue":-3,"x":11},{"sentimentName":"awful","y":-2,"sentimentValue":-3,"x":12},{"sentimentName":"cruel","y":-2,"sentimentValue":-3,"x":13},{"sentimentName":"kill","y":-1,"sentimentValue":-3,"x":14},{"sentimentName":"die","y":-1,"sentimentValue":-3,"x":15},{"sentimentName":"worse","y":-2,"sentimentValue":-3,"x":16},{"sentimentName":"worried","y":-1,"sentimentValue":-3,"x":17},{"sentimentName":"hated","y":-1,"sentimentValue":-3,"x":18},{"sentimentName":"died","y":-10,"sentimentValue":-3,"x":19}];
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'bar'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Sentiment Frequency'
            },
            xAxis: {
                labels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                tickWidth: 0,
                showEmpty: true
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: null
                },
                tickInterval: 1,
                padding: 0
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return '<b>' + this.point.sentimentName + '</b><br>Sentiment value: <b>' + this.point.sentimentValue + '</b><br/>' +
                        'Number of Uses: <b>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(Math.abs(this.point.y), 0) + '</b>';
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Negative',
                data: allNegativeData
            }, {
                name: 'Positive',
                data: allPositiveData
            }]
        });
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: The chart, by default, is grouping the points by x value - creating to spots side-by-side for each. You can either set **grouping: false**, or  **stacking: 'normal'** to your plotOptions to fix this:  https://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/9g95pobg/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing

```
plotOptions: {
     series: {
                stacking: 'normal'
             }
        },
```

From your chart options